# Browser login to page, handling with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium and I'm trying to automate loging in into one page.
But before actual login I'm getting popup for additional credentials.
Steps:
Paste address for page in new open browser (Firefox/Chrome).
Click enter,
Popup appears and it's asking about login and password to load page.
I fill them manually I'm getting page that I want to test.

[Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tAA5.png)

I can't inspect this popup element to get Xpaths or CSS Selectors and without them my selenium script fails.

When I'm trying to use `https://user:password@pageaddress.com` I'm getting page but nothing works.
I'm clicking "Sing In" but page is static.

Can you advise?

Best regards,
Piotr

Comment: Ok I've learned that this is Basic Authentication from page that I want to test, but how to handle it?  Using JavascriptExecutor is also not working.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Java, I tried from different angles. I'm focusing on firefox because Chrome is not in a default expected location. For chrome, I'm getting errors that binaries for chrome.exe cannot be found. Setting options.binary_location... is not working for me.

Comment: If you want to login by selenium, you need open login page. You need to get WebElement, then send Keys. I think this page will help you https://www.browserstack.com/guide/login-automation-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Testing on https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/, link 'Basic Authentication test'

```
package selenium;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class BasicAuhenticationTest extends WebDriverBase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        String protocol = "https://";
        String username = "guest";
        String password = "guest";
        String url = "jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Basic/";
        String urlFull = protocol + username + ":" + password + "@" + url;
        driver.get(urlFull);
        List<WebElement> paragraphs = driver.findElements(By.tagName("p"));
        for (WebElement paragraph: paragraphs) {
            System.out.println(paragraph.getText());
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
    
}
```

output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}) on port 29989
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Kvě 28, 2021 3:02:37 ODP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C


Your browser made it!
```